# Injecting property value for session timeout in Spring Session annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I have the following class:

```
@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 2000)
public class MyApplication {
```

I want to put in `maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds` a value from the Spring properties file (instead of the hardcoded `2000`). I can't use @Value there.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some annotations support SpEL, but most don't.  Annotations are processed at compile-time, they have no visibility to your properties.  This particular annotation will not support injection of properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically much simpler than this, even.

I assume you are using **Spring Boot**, so we will refer to `3.2.0-RC1` Spring bits (both Spring Boot and Spring Session). Earlier versions, especially in the `3.x` line, should functionally be the same.

You certainly don't want to be in the habit of directly extending the Spring Session for Redis, `RedisIndexedHttpSessionConfiguration` class ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/3.2.0-RC1/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisIndexedHttpSessionConfiguration.html)), partly because this is precisely the class that the `@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession` annotation "imports" ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/3.2.0-RC1/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession.html)), and both Spring Session as well as Spring Boot  make "customization" easy.

SPRING BOOT WAY:

You can simply set the following property in your Spring Boot `application.properties`:

```
# Your Spring Boot / Spring Session application.properties

spring.session.timeout=2000s
```

See Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.session.timeout) on the `spring.session.timeout` property.

The fallback property used by Spring Boot is:

`server.servlet.session.timeout`

This is evident from the Spring Boot auto-configuration ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.2.0-RC1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration.java#L78-L80)).

SPRING SESSION WAY (without Spring Boot):

It is even simple when you are not using Spring Boot. Simply register a bean of type `SessionRepositoryCustomizer` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/3.2.0-RC1/api/org/springframework/session/config/SessionRepositoryCustomizer.html)) from Spring Session, like so:

```java
@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession
class CustomSpringSessionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SessionRepositoryCustomizer<RedisIndexedSessionRepository> customizer(
        @Value("${my.session.timeout:2000}") int sessionTimeoutSeconds) {

        return repository -> 
            repository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(sessionTimeoutSeconds);   
    }
}
```

> NOTE: In fact, the Spring Session customization configuration code above is precisely what Spring Boot is doing itself, of course, with other Spring [Web [Session]] configuration taken into account; again see complete [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v3.2.0-RC1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration.java#L65-L85).

Then, your `my.session.timeout` property can be configured from any location that Spring's `Environment` supports as a "property source", including, but not limited to: Java System properties, properties files, Environment variables, and so on, including your own custom implementations as necessary, not unlike what Spring Boot provides for you already as well.

Answer (score 1):

As the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/3.1.0-RC1/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession.html) said

> More advanced configurations can extend
> RedisIndexedHttpSessionConfiguration instead.

Try to create your own configuration to override `RedisIndexedHttpSessionConfiguration`

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyRedisSessionProperties.class)
public class CustomRedisIndexedHttpSessionConfiguration extends RedisIndexedHttpSessionConfiguration {

    private final MyRedisSessionProperties myRedisSessionProperties;

    @Autowired
    void customize(MyRedisSessionProperties properties) {
        setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds((int) properties.getMaxInactiveInterval().getSeconds());
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties("my.redis.session")
    static class MyRedisSessionProperties {

        private Duration maxInactiveInterval;

        public Duration getMaxInactiveInterval() {
            return this.maxInactiveInterval;
        }

        public void setMaxInactiveInterval(Duration maxInactiveInterval) {
            this.maxInactiveInterval = maxInactiveInterval;
        }

    }
}
```

application.property

```
my.redis.session.max-inactive-interval=1h
```